# What is the image(range) of this function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Is the image(range) of $f(x)=x(\sin x + \cos x)$ equal to $(- \infty, + \infty)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Firstly, note that $f$ is continuous. Therefore the intermediate value theorem applies. This means that in order to show that the image of $f$ is $(-\infty,\infty)$, we only need to show that the image contains arbitrarily large and arbitrarily small values. Indeed, the intermediate value theorem will take care of all of the values in-between (dare I say, the intermediate ones).

Okay, so fix $M>0$. We want to find $y\ge M$ such that $y$ is in the image of $f$. Taking $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n\ge M$, we can set $y:=2\pi n$. Then $y>n\ge M$, and $y$ is in the image of $f$ because
$f(y)=y(\sin y+\cos y) = y(\sin(2\pi n)+\cos(2\pi n))=y(0+1)=y$.

I'll let you show that if $M<0$, then we can find $y\le M$ such that $y$ is in the image of $f$. (It's essentially the same argument.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following :

***sin(x) + cos(x)*** is equivalent to **sqrt(2) * [  sin(x) * cos(pie/4) + cos(x) * sin(pie/4) ]** , which in turn is equal to **sqrt(2) * [  sin(x+pie/4) ]**.

This implies, your function **F** is : **x * sqrt(2) * [  sin(x+pie/4) ]**.

Now ***x ranges to (-inf, +inf)*** whereas, **sin(x+pie/4) assumes elements in [-1, 1] periodically**.

Assume **a period of sin(x+pie/4) where it takes values in [-1,0] and x taking values in [a,b]** then *F takes values in [-a, 0]*, and in the very next interval where **sin(x+pie/4) assumes [0, 1] and x takes values in [b,c]** *F takes values in [0, c]*. Where a < b < c  , so *F assumes all values in range [-a, c] in interval [a, c].*

*Therefore, one can conclude product of these functions lies in (-inf, +inf), keeping the continuity of this function in mind.*

**Moreover, try googling its graph, it will be more alike a butterfly !**